# How to parse a unix directory by awk

Tags: awk

I need your help to parse a directory information by awk.
With the input below, can I get a full directory name and a filename for the each line?
That is, the directory structures vary and there is no rule for the number of directories.

### Input ( a list of file path )

```
/dir1/filename
/dir1/dir2/filename
/dir1/dir2/dir3/filename
/dir5/dir2/dir4/filename
```

### Output ( any space is okay between dir name and file name )

```
/dir1/         filename
/dir1/dir2/           filename
/dir1/dir2/dir3/                   filename
/dir5/dir2/dir4/          filename
```

Comment: Is this homework? What have you tried?

Comment: Is "Input" a file containing a list of file paths or are you just showing us your directory structure? If the former then yes you can use awk, if the latter then it's a job for shell, not awk, and you should be using `find` + `basename` or similar.

Comment: Do you necessarily need to use awk? This looks like a perfect job for `dirname` and `basename`. Otherwise, the "filename" (it may be a directory, you can't know unless you actually do a stat, which isn't really an awk thing) is the thing after the last "/" (so something like `match("$0, (/[^/]+)/([^/]+)$", a` and then pick start/length out of a).

Comment: I should split it with a directory name and a file name, then am going to put it into a database. After that, I will use that information to join other tables. I need to use a awk. Can you show me how can I accomplish that with Awk? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are more concise answers, but here's one based on `match` with help from Ed's comments:

```
{ 
  dname = substr($0, match($0, ".*/"), RLENGTH); 
  fname = substr($0, RLENGTH+1); 
  printf("%s %s\n", dname, fname); 
}
```

**Input**

```
/dir1/filename
/dir1/dir2/filename
/dir1/dir2/dir3/filename
/dir5/dir2/dir4/filename
../dir3/file
```

**Output**

```
/dir1/ filename
/dir1/dir2/ filename
/dir1/dir2/dir3/ filename
/dir5/dir2/dir4/ filename
../dir3/ file
```

Comment: I think length(line) should be 'length($0)'. Is that correct? With that, it works well and that is what I really want to get. simple. Thank you.

Comment: Whoops - yes, @Sigularity; fixed.

Comment: Ah. I learned that. It works. Actually, I don't mind any <blank><tab>. I just could get the dir name and filename without any indentation. That is it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like this MIGHT be what you're looking for:

```
$ awk '{sub("[^/]+$","\t&")}1' file
/dir1/  filename
/dir1/dir2/     filename
/dir1/dir2/dir3/        filename
/dir5/dir2/dir4/        filename
```

but any solution is going to have issues with file and/or directory names that contain whatever your separator character is for importing to the database you mention.

Answer (score 1):

`gawk`:

```
awk '{print gensub("(.*)/(.*)","\\1 \\2","g")}' File
```